# New directories and files are ignored

Tags: plasticscm

Heyo.

I don't know what happened to my workspace, but all my dirs and files are ignored by default and I need manually unignore them to make them visible in the tree.

For example, I added dir with the path

/Project/Assets/Resources/Graphic/Common/Sprites/Portraits

There is nothing in the ignore file that makes me supposed that this dir will be ignored

```
*.sln
*.csproj
*.db
*.suo
*.sln
*.csproj
*.blend
*.max
*.bmp
*(Auto-Backup)*
/Project/.vs
/Project/Library
/Project/EditorTempState.sav
/Project/UnityPackageManager
/Project/ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset
!ProjectVersion.txt
/Project/Temp
!*.tga
!*.sav
!/Project/Assets/Content/Story/QuestScripting
```

Until I add path to the ignore config as !/Project/Assets/Resources/Graphic/Common/Sprites/Portraits I can't see it in the tree and add to source control.

Please enlight me what I do wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was that I had global config ignore file (have no idea how it appeared) where my entire project was ignored

Find it here:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\plastic4\globalconfig